# When defining self.sock, get errors.python

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import socket, multiprocessing
class server():
    def __init__(self, socket):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    def accept(self):
        self.sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8080))
        self.sock.listen(5)
        conn, addr = self.sock.accept()
        print('Conn: {} Addr: {}'.format(conn, addr))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.accept(socket)
```

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "server.py", line 11, in
> <module>
>     server.accept(socket)   File "server.py", line 6, in accept
>     self.sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8080)) AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'sock'
```

Comment: `accept` method is an instance method not a class method

Comment: You aren't even using the socket attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass a socket instance since you already define one in your class definition.

```
import socket
class server():

    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def accept(self):
        self.sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8080))
        self.sock.listen(5)
        conn, addr = self.sock.accept()
        print('Conn: {} Addr: {}'.format(conn, addr))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    s = server()
    s.accept()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an instance of the server class first:

```
s = server(socket)
s.accept()
```

Comment: OP is not even using the socket attribute, in addition socket will refer to the module you import